# AngularJS Dynamic table with Mysql database,jsp and servlets

Tags: java, mysql, angularjs, json, servlets

I have a JSP like bellow

```
<div id="progressR" class="collapse">
    <form class="form-horizontal" ng-controller="progressController">

        <div class="form-group">
            <p></p>
            <label for="projectTitle" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                Report No: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10   ">
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="progress.no" required>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                    <option>7</option>
                    <option>8</option>
                    <option>9</option>
                    <option>10</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="projectTitle" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                End date: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="date" class="form-control"
                    ng-model="progress.enddate" required>
            </div>
            <label for="projectTitle" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                End Time: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="time" class="form-control"
                    ng-model="progress.endtime">

            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="SAVE"
            ng-click="insertProgressData()" />

    </form>
    <div class="table table-responsive"
        ng-controller="reportListController">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>ReportNo</th>
                    <th>End Date</th>
                    <th>End Time</th>
                    <th>....</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in myArray">
                    <td>{{x.reportNo}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.endDate}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.endTime}}</td>
                    <td> remove </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want is after I click the save button all the data in the input boxes should go to the database and it show update the table with the new values I just entered without reloading the page. I used Json to do that and data insertion part is working fine, but it does not update the table!, once I refresh the page then it shows the changes

Here is my 
AngularJS code :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('progressController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.insertProgressData = function() {
        console.log($scope.progress);
        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/ProjectSupportSystem/InsertProgressReportInfo',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data : JSON.stringify($scope.progress)
        }).then(function successCallback(data) {
            console.log(data);
            updateTable();
        },function errorCallback (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });


    };

    $scope.updateTable = function() {
        $scope.myArray = [];
        $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/ProjectSupportSystem/DoViewPReportDetailsList'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.myArray = response.data;
            console.log('success');
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log('error');
        });

    };

});
```

Also I can say that servlets are sending JSon without any errors
What is the problem of this code?